# Fork and child/parent processes

Tags: c, fork

I'm studying for a midterm for my OS class and was looking at this code example. On my system (OS X Yosemite) I'm getting ONE TWO FOUR TWO THREE, so it seems like the child process runs and outputs first before the parent does, despite the lack of a wait() function. Is this expected behavior on all systems, or could it also be ONE TWO THREE TWO FOUR, or even something different?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int rc;
  printf( "ONE\n" );
  rc = fork();
  printf( "TWO\n" );
  if ( rc == 0 ) { printf( "THREE\n" ); }
  if ( rc > 0 ) { printf( "FOUR\n" ); }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the only thing you're guaranteed here is that "ONE" will print first. The rest is variable.

Comment: Why are the rest of the outputs not guaranteed?

Comment: They're guaranteed to print - of course - but at any given moment the other process may get some time. Edit: they're actually *not* guaranteed; fork could fail.

Comment: Remove the `\n`s and you might get even more (surprising) results.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: It is also guaranteed that `THREE` and `FOUR` are each preceded by at least one `TWO`.

Comment: @alk, that's right; good catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll print `ONE`, followed by:

For the parent process:

```
TWO
FOUR
```

For the child process:

```
TWO
THREE
```

The two processes are distinct with no synchronization between them.  They run their due course, at their own timings.

So say if the parent was faster than the child, you could get `TWO` `FOUR` followed by `TWO` `THREE`.  If the child was faster, you could get `TWO` `THREE` followed by `TWO` `FOUR`.  If they're roughly the same, you could get a result where their outputs are intermixed, such as `TWO` `TWO` `FOUR` `THREE`, or any combination thereof.